# HLSL: Cut a texture radially

Tags: hlsl

I'm currently having a pixel shader:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0   
{

float4 color = tex2D(Sampler0,coords);
float dx = coords.x - 0.5f;
float dy = coords.y - 0.5f;

float tpos = dx * dx + dy * dy;
if(tpos <= 0.25f && tpos > 0.25f-width )
    return color;
else
    return float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

This way I am able to draw a circle. But how do I cut the circle, e.g. draw 30 degrees circle? Or 60 degrees one? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the intrinsic `atan2` ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)) to compute the angle of your fragment in relation to the circle center and then do a clipping like your distance clipping.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it with:
`float degree = -180 + dg;
if (radians(degree) > atan2(dy,dx))
return color;
else
...`